# Wordpress query not changing with onchange form submit

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I have a page that displays all the staff members, which are grouped by company. Each staff member is a custom post type. I have a dropdown menu and a submit button to filter the staff by company, which works fine.

```
<div id="choose">
<form name="selectCompany" method="post" action=""> 
<span>Select Company: </span>
<select name="company" >
<option value="All Staff">All Staff</option>
<option value="Company 1" <?php echo $yourgroup; ?>>Company 1</option>
<option value="Company 2" <?php echo $yourpower; ?>>Company 2</option>
<option value="Company 3" <?php echo $yourelectrical; ?>>Company 3/option>
<option value="Company 4" <?php echo $newmills; ?>>Company 4"</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

The Wordpress query I'm using is (where `$company` is the value from the dropdown menu):

```
if ($company != "All Staff") {

    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'staff_members',
                     'orderby' => 'title',
                     'order' => 'ASC',
                     'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                    'key' => 'company',
                                    'value' => $company,
                                    'compare' => '=',
                                    ),
                            ),
                      );
}
else {

    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'staff_members',
                      'orderby' => 'title',
                      'order' => 'ASC',);
}

if (empty($_POST['submit'])) { //Set default value for displaying staff

    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'staff_members',
              'orderby' => 'title',
              'order' => 'ASC',);

    $company = "All Staff";
}

?>

<p><span class="display">Displaying Staff for <?php echo $company; ?></span></p>

<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
<div class="staff">
                    <div class="photo">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="shadowbox[staff-1]">
                    <?php
                     if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail()  ) { //Recommended way of doing it
                            the_post_thumbnail();

                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/staff-default.gif" />';
                        } 
                     ?>
                    </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="name"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="shadowbox[staff-2]"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <div class="title">
                    <?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'job_title', true ) ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php // echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'company', true ) ); ?>

            </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This all works fine, however I want to remove the submit button  and just do it when the list changes. I changed it to `<select name="company" onchange="this.form.submit()">`. It submits the form and the page reloads but it doesn't actually filter the staff. I don't know why using a submit button works but but using `onchange` doesn't.

Comment: what happens if you add <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Go">  in the form? I'm guessing that there is a test somewere that fails without the submit button ...

Comment: I added that in, but then the form doesn't submit at all.

Comment: that again makes me think there are more rules in the code (if's) that we have to see in order to determin what breaks the submition... can you share more of the code?

Comment: I've added the full code for the page